# docker-compose up --build cannor find module

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

When I start my container (node web app), the docker build it's fine but when I run my container this issues appear

The issue:

```
root@DESKTOP-PP3RIAT:/home/daramog/ezops-test-matheus-morozetti# docker-compose up
Recreating ezops-test-matheus-morozetti_web_1 ... done
Attaching to ezops-test-matheus-morozetti_web_1
web_1  | node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:944
web_1  |   throw err;
web_1  |   ^
web_1  |
web_1  | Error: Cannot find module '/app/server.js'
web_1  |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:941:15)
web_1  |     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:774:27)
web_1  |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
web_1  |     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
web_1  |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
web_1  |   requireStack: []
web_1  | }
ezops-test-matheus-morozetti_web_1 exited with code 1
```

My Dockerfile:

```sh
FROM node:alpine as builder

WORKDIR '/src'

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm set strict-ssl false
RUN npm install


COPY . ..
RUN node ./server.js

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

My dockerfile.dev

```sh
FROM node:alpine

WORkDIR /src

COPY ["package.json","package-lock.json","/"]
RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

My docker-compose

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    volumes:
      - .:/src
    command: ["node", "server.js"]
```

Comment: The `volumes:` in the `docker-compose.yml` file hide everything in the image, including its `node_modules` tree.  Does removing this block help?  (You can use an ordinary Node environment on the host to develop your application, even if you're going to eventually deploy it in Docker.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this file exist within the container?

> Error: Cannot find module '/app/server.js'

From your docker-compose I see you setup the workdir to /src, and then you are copying that file into /src
But what you are trying to run, is looking for server.js under /app